# display the picture of the products category

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to display the picture of the products category on the map.
I want to show the category image
I tried many of the following WordPress functions and when I got vardump it gave me an array
this is the code of my map
In this section  I want to show the image instead of the icon

```
        <?php

     
        $args = array('post_type' => 'product', 'post_status' => 'publish', 'posts_per_page' => -1);
        $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
        ?>
        <?php if ($wp_query->have_posts()) :
            $posts = $wp_query->posts;

            $GLOBALS['all_ads']=$posts;
            $lenght = count($posts); ?>
            <ul class="row items ad-listing">
                <?php for ($i = 0; $i < $lenght; $i++) {
                    $single_post = $posts[$i];
        
                    $terms = wp_get_post_terms($single_post->ID, 'city_categories', array('order' => 'DESC'));
                    $parent_id = $terms[0]->parent;
                    $parent_id_1 = $terms[1]->parent;
                    $city_term = get_term_by('id', $parent_id, 'city_categories');
                   $name = $city_term->name;
                    $term_id = $terms[0]->term_id;
                    $term_id_two = $terms[1]->term_id;
                    $ad_type = get_post_meta($single_post->ID, 'ad_type','true');

                    $parent_id = $parent_id ? $parent_id :$parent_id_1;

                    if ($city_term_id == $term_id || $city_term_id == $term_id_two){
                        $data['lat'] = get_post_meta($single_post->ID, '_ad_latitude', true);
                        $data['long'] = get_post_meta($single_post->ID, '_ad_longitude', true);

                        $phone = get_post_meta($single_post->ID , 'shmarhtmascabt_v_shmarhtmascabt_m' , true);
                        $address = trim(get_post_meta($single_post->ID , 'adrs_v_shmarhtmascabt_m' , true));
                        $type = wp_get_post_terms($single_post->ID, 'product_cat')[0]->name;
                        $title = $single_post->post_title;
                        $ad_link = get_permalink($single_post->ID);
                     
                       $sc_studi_cat_icon = get_term_meta($term_id->term_id, array( 1680,470 ), true);
                     print_r($sc_studi_cat_icon);
                      $img_cat=wp_get_attachment_image($sc_studi_cat_icon,array('71', '76'));
      $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($single_post->ID), '', false, '' );
                      $sc_studi_cat_icon = get_term_meta($type->term_id, 'sc_studi_cat_icon', true);
                       $img_cat=wp_get_attachment_image($sc_studi_cat_icon,array('71', '76') , false , 'src');
                    var_dump($img_cat);
                        $data['text']="<div class='map-div-container'><div><a href='{$ad_link}'><h4>{$title}</h4></a></div>";
                        if ($phone){$data['text'].="<div><i class='fas fa-phone' style='font-size: 10px;'></i><b>ØªÙ„ÙÙ†:</b> {$phone}</div>";}
                        if ($address){$data['text'].="<div><i class='fas fa-map-marker-alt'></i><b>Ø¢Ø¯Ø±Ø³:</b> {$address}</div>";}
                        if ($type){$data['text'].="<div><i class='far fa-folder'></i><b>&#1606;&#1608;&#1593;:</b> {$type}</div></div>";}
                        $data['text']=urldecode($data['text']);
                        $map_data[$single_post->ID] = $data;
                    }

                    if (($state_term_id === $parent_id || $state_term_id[0] === $parent_id) && ($ad_type == 1936)):
```

It will be a great help if you could guide me how to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $type3 = wp_get_post_terms($single_post->ID, 'product_cat')[0];


$category_thumbnail = get_woocommerce_term_meta($type3->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true);
$image = wp_get_attachment_url($category_thumbnail);
```